# How to play local video file on loop on an excel userform?

Tags: excel, vba, video, userform

How to play local video file on loop on an excel userform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ActiveX control called Microsoft Media Player which is found via the Toolbox and then Additional Controls.  Then set the url in the ide.

To get the video to loop requires some code thus

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    WindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.setMode "loop", True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks is there any way I can embed that in userform and how do I pass the filepath parameter?

Comment: @newguy the answer says it already. Toolbox > Additional Controls.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes sorry I was actually looking for .URL property of the Media Player.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Hi any idea how can we make the player's position height and width constant? It keeps changing depending on the resolution of the file I select. I checked properties but I can't find anything that will keep it intact in its position. Maybe I can use it in a frame?

Comment: @newguy no idea, I've never used Excel to play videos off YouTube.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Okay thanks btw I am playing local media file.